# Insert using DB link from one DB to another

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am trying to copy records from one DB to another. Below is my query and the error i am getting:

```
INSERT INTO RDW.rdw_sdm_trader_sls_brn_cst_v
SELECT * from RDW.rdw_sdm_trader_sls_brn_cst_v@DB_DWHPRD_RDW
WHERE DIVISION_CODE = 'EH' and rownum <= 100
```

-

```
*Error at Command Line:4 Column:0*        
*Error report:*  
*SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table*
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"*  
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which*
           *map to a non-key-preserved table.*  
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.*
```

Comment: Is `RDW.rdw_sdm_trader_sls_brn_cst_v` a view?  If so, it does not appear that the view as defined can be inserted into.  You may need to create an `instead of` trigger on the view in order to make it insertable.  Or you may need to insert into the various base tables directly.  Or you may be able to redefine the view so that it is key preserved.

Comment: Yes it is a view. And its definition has many tables in the join condition. Is there any way by which i can copy the data?

Comment: Unless the view can be redefined to be key-preserved, you'd need to write the `instead of` trigger if you want to insert into the view.